# AppFabric on Windows Server 2016 - "error running cmdlet 'out-lineoutput'"

Tags: powershell, iis, appfabric, windows-server-2016, iis-10

Trying to deploy some software that uses AppFabric in IIS.  Yes, I already know AppFabric is deprecated; I didn't architect this software, so don't look at me!  I also have the CU7 update for AppFabric installed.

I'm on Windows Server 2016 with IIS 10.  No matter what I click on involving AppFabric in IIS, I get an error: `The method or operation is not implemented.`

Opening up the Event logs, I see that the  method in question is a PowerShell commandlet: `error running cmdlet 'out-lineoutput'. The method or operation is not implemented.`

`Out-LineOutput` allegedly was introduced in PowerShell 5, and I've read that it only exists in regular PowerShell (not ISE).  Beyond that, I haven't found any reference to that commandlet in regards to AppFabric.

What's driving me extra nuts is that I have a sandbox machine, also running Server 2016, where everything is working OK.  I have confirmed that:

- the `PSModulePath` environment variable is the same on both; and
- running `Get-Module` at a Powershell prompt shows the same modules installed on both.

I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling AppFabric and the CU7 patch, adding my Application Pool Identity(ies) to the `AS_Administrators` group . . . nothing is working.  Help me, Stack Overflow!

Comment: [`Out-LineOutput` is not an external command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849734.aspx).

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 exactly... so why is it `not implemented`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out this was due to a registry key entry setting logging.  In regedit, go to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\Transcription
```

Check out the `EnableTranscripting` property.  If this is a `1`, change it to a `0`.